# How to add Play Framework into existing web application in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, web-applications, playframework

Is it possible to use Play Framework within other quite ordinary web application which uses Jersey and GWT? This application has got the `web.xml`, GWT entry point etc and Glassfish as application server. 
All Play samples don't have `web.xml` but have conf/routes.
First issue is how to add the possibility to use Play in the existing web application in Eclipse. In google I can find how to create Play application using Play console (command line) and the import the a project into Eclipse. But I want to use Play in existing project, not new.

The second issue is how to handle requests to REST, GWT and Play.
To handle a REST request (like `http://localhost/Appname/rest/param/otherParam`), the `web.xml` contains

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.rest</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

GWT requests (like `http://localhost/Appname/param/otherParam`) are handled thanks to `Appname.html`.

And how to add Play request handling? The routes are defined in the conf/routes but how to integrate this with REST and GWT request kind?

Answer (score 0):

Play! is a **full-stack** framework. Either you use Play! or you use servlets (or Vert.x, or whatever), not both. In Play! 1.x there was a GWT plugin though (no idea if there's one for Play! 2)